# Transferring specific data from one excel file to another using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I just started learning Python and I need help with a script my internship asked me to write.

I have a csv file (sheet1.csv) and I need to extract data from only two of the columns which have the headers referenceID and PartNumber that correspond to each other. I need to update a separate csv file called sheet2.csv which also contains the two columns referenceID and PartNumber however many of the PartNumber cells are empty.

Basically I need to fill in the “PartNumber” field with the values from sheet1.  From the research I’ve done I’ve decided using dictionaries are a solid approach to writing this script (I think).  So far I have been able to read the files and create two dictionaries with the referenceIDs as the keys and the PartNumber as values… Here is what I have showing an example of what the dictionaries look like.

```
import csv 
a = open('sheet1.csv', 'rU')
b = open('sheet2.csv', 'rU')
csvReadera = csv.DictReader(a)
csvReaderb = csv.DictReader(b)
a_dict = {}
b_dict = {}

for line in csvReadera:
    a_dict[line["ReferenceID"]] = line["PartNumber"]
print(a_dict)

for line in csvReaderb:
    b_dict[line["ReferenceID"]] = line["PartNumber"]
print(b_dict)

a_dict = {'R150': 'PN000123', 'R331': 'PN000873', 'C774': 'PN000064', 'L7896': 'PN000447', 'R0640': 'PN000878', 'R454': 'PN000333'}
b_dict = {'C774': '', 'R331': '', 'R454': '', 'L7896': 'PN000000', 'R0640': '', 'R150': 'PN000333'}
```

How can I compare the two dictionaries and fill in/overwrite the missing values for b-dict and then write to sheet2?  Certainly, there must be more efficient methods than what I have come up with, but I have never used Python before so please forgive my pitiful attempt!

Comment: I've just tried to make the first paragraph a bit easier on the eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the pandas library.

```
import padas as pd

#this is how you read
dfa = pd.read_csv("sheet1.csv")
dfb = pd.read_csv("sheet2.csv")
```

let s jus take the dicts you defined as testdata

```
a_dict = {'R150': 'PN000123', 'R331': 'PN000873', 'C774': 'PN000064', 'L7896': 'PN000447', 'R0640': 'PN000878', 'R454': 'PN000333'}
b_dict = {'C774': '', 'R331': '', 'R454': '', 'L7896': 'PN000000', 'R0640': '', 'R150': 'PN000333'}
dfar = pd.DataFrame(a_dict.items(), columns = ['ReferenceID', 'PartNumber'])
dfbr = pd.DataFrame(b_dict.items(), columns = ['ReferenceID', 'PartNumber'])
dfa = dfar[['ReferenceID', 'PartNumber']]
dfa.columns = ['ReferenceIDA', 'PartNumberA']
dfb = dfbr[['ReferenceID', 'PartNumber']]
dfb.columns = ['ReferenceIDB', 'PartNumberB']
```

you get this

```
  In [97]: dfa
Out[97]: 
  ReferenceIDA PartNumberA
0         R331    PN000873
1         R454    PN000333
2        L7896    PN000447
3         R150    PN000123
4         C774    PN000064
5        R0640    PN000878

In [98]: dfb
Out[98]: 
  ReferenceIDB PartNumberB
0         R331            
1         R454            
2        R0640            
3         R150    PN000333
4         C774            
5        L7896    PN000000
```

now

```
    In [67]: cd = pd.concat([dfa,dfb], axis=1)

    In [68]: cd
    Out[68]: 
  ReferenceIDA PartNumberA ReferenceIDB PartNumberB
0         R331    PN000873         R331            
1         R454    PN000333         R454            
2        L7896    PN000447        R0640            
3         R150    PN000123         R150    PN000333
4         C774    PN000064         C774            
5        R0640    PN000878        L7896    PN000000




cd["res"] = cd.apply(lambda x : x["PartNumberB"] if x["PartNumberB"] else x["PartNumberA"], axis=1)

 cd
Out[106]: 
  ReferenceIDA PartNumberA ReferenceIDB PartNumberB       res
0         R331    PN000873         R331              PN000873
1         R454    PN000333         R454              PN000333
2        L7896    PN000447        R0640              PN000447
3         R150    PN000123         R150    PN000333  PN000333
4         C774    PN000064         C774              PN000064
5        R0640    PN000878        L7896    PN000000  PN000000
```

this is what you wanted

just set

```
dfbr['PartNumber'] = cd['res']
```

and dump to csv

```
dfbr.to_csv('sheet2.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  The pandas library looks like an extremal powerful tool for my type of situation however I'd rather avoid external libraries for the time being.  Again, Thank you for your time.